# Cap invoke and sudo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano

I want to install a gem on all my application servers, but gem install requires sudo access - how can I enable sudo only for running this capistrano command?

In other words, I don't wish to use sudo for all my deployment recipes, just when I invoke this command on the command line.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Found it - cap invoke COMMAND="*command that requires sudo*" SUDO=1

Comment: Hi, It was working fine with Capistrano 2. Do you know the similar command in Capistrano 3 ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure I understand the question, but I think you're asking how to restrict sudo to the one specific command and not have to grant unlimited capacity for mischief to all of your Ruby developers.

/etc/sudoers can be set up to restrict the commands which users are allowed to invoke as root. It is commonly set to ALL, but you can provide just a list of the allowed commands.

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to use unix ACLs or similar permissions for this.  Give the deploy user sudoer access, then you can call `run "sudo do_something"` and it will be sudo-level access only for that call.